# JWPlayer 7.8.7 File could not be played issue

Tags: jwplayer

I am using JWPlayer 7.8.7, My configuration is

```
           jwplayer('player').setup({
                    file: "https://<url>/playlist.m3u8",
                    image: <image path>,
                    type: "mp4",
                    autostart: true,
                    base: "/static/js/libs/jwplayer/",
                    skin: "bekle",
                    primary: 'html5',
                    fallback : false,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 350,
                    aspectratio: "16:9",
                    stretching: "fill"
               });
```

Here when I try to load video, its giving File could not be played error, Whats wrong ? my url is working I can access that url and able to download m3u8 file also download m3u8 and able to play it successfully.

```
* cant expose actual urls
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it work in Safari or Edge?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) "type" should be "hls" not "mp4"

2) Make sure you are using a Premium license key (https://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/)